# React Jsx and JS file conditional

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, conditional-statements, jsx

Ok so here's the deal I'm working in react and I got this website me and team are working on for a senior project.

So i've got this functioning login page with its code below called component.jsx its got all i need including text inputs for customers. however We want to add validation to it so that when the text is empty(like if a customer just forget and hit submit) it would send a message letting them know.

essentially Im asking for a conditional only issue is that jsx dosent rly do conditionals like IF/else

so I wanted to do it in a sepereate js file (validate.js) and I've looked everywhere I cant find anything about how to make an effective function/class or whatever for an input in a JS file then impart that into the jsx file where the code is.

So right now Im looking fr guidance on how to achieve that goal and was wondering if anybody had any ideas(websites with this, similar questions or just know the answer).

If you do just know the answer on how to do this please keep it simple that way I can look back at it latter to understand incase I miss you

currently the JS file(validate.js) I have is empty

[login website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnXaO.png)
[JSX code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJ96m.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little exemple, there is plenty of way to manage errors, here is one.

```js
const Login = () => {

  // our values state
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState({email: "", password: ""});
  // our errors state
  const [errors, setErrors] = React.useState({email: "", password: ""});

  const handleChange = (event) => {
  
    // onChange return an event object containing the name of the input and its current value
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    
    // update values in state
    setValues({...values, [name]: value})
    
    // reset error for that input on change
    if(errors[name].length > 0) setErrors({ ...errors, [name]: "" })
    
  }
  
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
  
    // on submit we prevent default behavior
    event.preventDefault();
    
    // check if our inputs are valid
    const {hasErrors, errors} = validateInputs();
    
    if(!hasErrors) {
      // input are not empty
      // you can do whatever you want here
    } else {
      // there is errors, update our state to display them on next render
      setErrors(errors);
    }
  }
  
  const isEmpty = (value) => {
    return value === "";
  }
  
  const validateInputs = () => {
  
    // iterate each input value
    const errors = Object.keys(values).reduce((errors, current) => {
       // you can add any check here
      if(isEmpty(values[current])) {
        errors[current] = `${current.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + current.slice(1)} is required.`;
      }
      return errors;
    }, {});
    
    const hasErrors = Object.keys(errors).length > 0;
    
    return { errors, hasErrors };
  }

  return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" onChange={handleChange} />
        { errors.email.length > 0 && ( <div className="error-message" >{errors.email}</div> ) }
        
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" onChange={handleChange} />
        { errors.password.length > 0 && ( <div className="error-message" >{errors.password}</div> ) }

        <button type="submit" >Log in</button>
      </form>
  )
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Login />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

input, button {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0.3rem;
}

.error-message {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple and easiest way is to add required:{true}  into your  attribute.
example here:

```
<Form.Control
      type="text"
      placeholder="Enter Skills"
      value={Skill}
      required={true}
      onChange={(e) => setSkill(e.target.value)}
    ></Form.Control>
```